# In Slickgrid 's column set dynamically, so as per colum wise gridmenu not show

Tags: angular5, angular-components, slickgrid

I'm new in angular with slickgrid and i have already spent some of hours.
my issue is

=> Single angular slickgrid in test.component.html file and set required attributes like name,columnDefinitions,dataset and gridOptions etc.

=> I have set columnDefinitions dynamically means on dropdown change i change columnDefinitions columns.

=> So when i click to gridmenu option it's see old columns name with new column

i want to clear old columnnames in gridmenu which show in right side in angular slickgrid.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Changing the column definitions dynamically is really not ideal and shouldn't be used unless you really have to. Angular-Slickgrid keeps 2 array internally, `visibleColumns` and `allColumns` and if you change the columns without updating the `columnDefinitions` set in the `<angular-slickgrid>` then you are looking for trouble. The `visibleColumns` array exist because you can set a `presets` with hidden columns and those won't be part of the `visibleColumns` array. I never change the definition dynamically, instead I use `*ngIf` to show the grid when it's ready, that is a better way to do it.

Comment: If you are change the column definitions that is connected to the `<angular-slickgrid>` but it's not reflected in the grid, then try forcing Angular to do a dirty check. You can do this with a shallow copy like this `this.columnDefinitions = { ...this.columnDefinitions };`

Comment: @ghiscoding thanks for reply
=> Actually i set this.columnDefinitions dynamically and it's working fine, but issue is when columnDefinitions field change it's also need to change in slikgridmenu, right?
so in slikgrid gridmenu(which in top right corner) show old and new both column fields, this is actual issue.

Comment: I already replied you on the reason and a possible solutions, if that doesn't work then you're out of luck. So re-read carefully both comments I wrote.

Comment: hey, thanks, i understood the somewhat and it might be useful.